# SimpleMessageListenerContainer - ClassNotFoundException warning on AMQP receive message

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-amqp

I have just updated my application to version `spring-integration-amqp-5.2.4.RELEASE` and when I receive message from queue everything works fine, but I noticed warning `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` in `DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper` class. I use custom `DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper` with `IdClassMapping`. How can I avoid tracking the warning?

```
@Bean
public Jackson2JavaTypeMapper defaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper() {
    DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper defaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper = new DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper();
    Map<String, Class<?>> classMapping = new HashMap<>();
    classMapping.put("event.request", RequestDTO.class);
    defaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.setIdClassMapping(classMapping);
    return defaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper;
}

@Bean
public MessageConverter messageConverterJson(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    Jackson2JsonMessageConverter messageConverter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(objectMapper);
    messageConverter.setJavaTypeMapper(defaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper());
    return messageConverter;
}
```

LOG warning

```
o.s.i.a.support.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper  : error occurred while mapping from AMQP properties to MessageHeaders

java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: event.request
    at org.springframework.integration.mapping.support.JsonHeaders.getClassForValue(JsonHeaders.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.mapping.support.JsonHeaders.buildResolvableType(JsonHeaders.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.createJsonResolvableTypHeaderInAny(DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.java:169)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.extractStandardHeaders(DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.java:155)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.extractStandardHeaders(DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.java:61)
    at org.springframework.integration.mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper.toHeaders(AbstractHeaderMapper.java:266)
    at org.springframework.integration.mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper.toHeadersFromRequest(AbstractHeaderMapper.java:203)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.toHeadersFromRequest(DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.java:337)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.toHeadersFromRequest(DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.java:61)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundGateway$Listener.convert(AmqpInboundGateway.java:351)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundGateway$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundGateway.java:314)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1579)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1498)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1421)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:963)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:913)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:81)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1284)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1190)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: event.request
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:92)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:282)
    at org.springframework.integration.mapping.support.JsonHeaders.getClassForValue(JsonHeaders.java:86)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have already mapped an AMQP message into the target payload via `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter`, it looks like you don't need any incoming headers at all.

To avoid that warning and extra mapping job, I suggest you to inject a custom `AmqpHeaderMapper`. Probably just an extension to the `DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper`, when you return an empty headers for mapping from request:

```
amqpInboundGateway.setHeaderMapper(new DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper(null, null) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, Object> toHeadersFromRequest(MessageProperties source) {
            return new HashMap<>();
        }

    });
```

On the other hand it is just a WARN: you can simply decrease logging level to ERROR for that `org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound` category.

The point is that we can't just ignore such an error if we can't find a class for the `__Type__` header. The framework can't make an assumption what you expect.

Another possible way to fix is to remove those JSON header from the `MessageProperties.getHeaders()` in the `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` extension when you override `fromMessage()`.